# “The connection has timed out.” in iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I Create a New Website in Windows IIS , It has been working for several months

but i get this error today.

```
“The connection has timed out.”
the server 192.168.1.7 at is taking too long to respond
```

i set binding

[image]

and get this error

[image]

Comment: check this server 192.168.1.7 is estable or not

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: open server 192.168.1.7 and if you enter  and go to iis and see application

Comment: dont open application

Comment: what ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocwrqOGxoHc

Comment: I set 192.168.1.7 in binding host name

Comment: you set port 85 .and click on link browse in right menu  in iis manager

Comment: my port is 80, i click on link in right menu but get error in image2.I used this setup for several months and everything was fine. but today i open this, get error

Comment: Try to clear the host name, and then use localhost to access your website.

Comment: https://www.jivrus.com/resources/articles/technical/site-took-too-long-to-respond

Comment: @YurongDai thanks a lot, i change it , it is ok in server , but when i use this in other system in server What address should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by other systems on the server? Do you have multiple virtual machines installed on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

you can also be set in the web.config (example is for 2 minutes, 120 seconds):

```
<limits connectionTimeout="00:02:00" />
```

Comment: i set this in application pool

Comment: set it on your web.config

Comment: I set this but get eror again

Comment: can we see your error image on form or request ?

Comment: 192.168.1.7 is your IP address?

Comment: set for host name

Comment: can you search http://localhost:80. chack it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the host name, and then use localhost to access your website in server.If you do not access your website locally, you need to use the IP address to access. If you have registered a domain name and completed the binding, you can also use the domain name to access.